# "No XU MBean found" Diagnostics warning for the Business Rules Service on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

When I run the diagnostics on the Rule Execution Server console of the Business Rules service, I see a warning saying "No XU MBean found". Is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this warning is expected if no rulesets have been executed yet. Once a ruleset has been executed (and hence the the XU or the Execution unit has been called at least once), this warning disappears.